# Reducing frequency of a signal

Tags: matlab, frequency, speech-processing, downsampling

I have a signal that I want to make it sound like a whisper. This is probably better than using a voice conversion system, but I was just want to do some experimenting before.

I was thinking maybe try to reduce the frequency of the signal? Maybe downsampling? Does anyone have a idea how to get closer to a whisper/unvoiced signal from a voiced signal?